# how to run the clojure main from gradle application plugin

Tags: gradle, clojure, clojure-java-interop

I've main clojure [file](https://github.com/rajcspsg/clojure-gradle-demo/blob/master/src/main/clojure/main/main.clj) -

```
(ns main.main
  (:gen-class))

(defn -main
      "I don't do a whole lot ... yet."
      [& args]
      (println "Hello, World!"))
```

I've [build.gradle](https://github.com/rajcspsg/clojure-gradle-demo/blob/master/build.gradle) file -

```
plugins {
    id 'dev.clojurephant.clojure' version '0.7.0-alpha.1'
    id 'application'
}

group 'org.example'
version '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
repositories {
    maven {
        name = 'Clojars'
        url = 'https://repo.clojars.org'
    }
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    implementation 'org.clojure:clojure:1.11.1'

    testRuntimeOnly 'org.ajoberstar:jovial:0.3.0'

    devImplementation 'org.clojure:tools.namespace:1.3.0'
    
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1'
}

tasks.withType(Test) {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

application {
    mainClassName("main.main")
}
```

Now I tried to run the gradle application using command `gradle run` and encountered below error -

> Error: Could not find or load main class main.main
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: main.main

I tried some more application configuration but didn't work -

```
application {
    mainClass = "clojure.main"
    mainModule = "main.main"
}
```

what is the correct value of `mainClass` and `mainModule`.

Comment: You are probably missing `(:gen-class)` in your ns declaration. Then the name should simply be `main.main`. See https://clojure.org/reference/compilation#_gen_class_examples

Comment: @JurajMartinka I tried your suggestion but I it didn't worked. I updated my question as per your suggestion as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got it working. Missed the below [config](https://github.com/rajcspsg/clojure-gradle-demo/blob/master/build.gradle#L31-L37) -

```
clojure {
  builds {
    main {
      aotAll()
    }
  }
}
```